# Accelerating an image web scraper

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written my first web scraper, which (surprisingly) does the job. I'm scraping a popular [comic website](http://www.poorlydrawnlines.com/archive/) for the images (there are over `900` of them) but the problem is the scraper is way too slow.

For example, if I download a sample of `10` comics it takes an average of `4` to `5` secs per image (a total of `> 40 secs` for the sample), which is a bit too slow if you ask me because each image is approx. the size of `80KB` to `800KB`.

I've read I could switch to `lxml` to do the scraping asynchronously but the package is not compatible with Python 3.6.

I've tried this:

```
pip3 install lxml
```

Just to get this:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-lxml (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-lxml
```

So my question is ***how to accelerate the scraper?***

Maybe my scraping logic is to be blamed? Finally, is there a way to scrape a webpage only for the relevant part?

Here's the code. I've removed all eye-candy & input validation - full code [here](https://github.com/baduker/poorlywrittenscraper)

```
import re
import time
import requests
import itertools
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def generate_comic_link(array, num):
  for link in itertools.islice(array, 0, num):
    yield link

def grab_image_src_url(link):
  req = requests.get(link)
  comic = req.text
  soup = bs(comic, 'html.parser')
  for i in soup.find_all('p'):
    for img in i.find_all('img', src=True):
      return img['src']

def download_image(link):
  file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
  with open(file_name, "wb") as file:
    response = get(url)
    file.write(response.content)

def fetch_comic_archive():
  url = 'http://www.poorlydrawnlines.com/archive/'
  req = requests.get(url)
  page = req.text
  soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
  all_links = []
  for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    all_links.append(link.get('href'))
  return all_links

def filter_comic_archive(archive):
  pattern = re.compile(r'http://www.poorlydrawnlines.com/comic/.+')
  filtered_links = [i for i in archive if pattern.match(i)]
  return filtered_links

all_comics = fetch_comic_archive()
found_comics = filter_comic_archive(all_comics)

print("\nThe scraper has found {} comics.".format(len(found_comics)))
print("How many comics do you want to download?")
n_of_comics = int(input(">> ").strip())

start = time.time()
for link in generate_comic_link(found_comics, n_of_comics):
  print("Downloading: {}".format(link)
  url = grab_image_src_url(link)
  download_image(url)
end = time.time()
print("Successfully downloaded {} comics in {:.2f} seconds.".format(n_of_comics, end - start))
```

Comment: Any reason you can't call the `download_image` method in parallel (which is presumably where your main delays happen)

Comment: @match I guess the only reason is my inadequate coding skills. I'll give it a shot and time it again. Actually, I thought it might have been the generator to be at fault here. Thanks for the input!

Comment: I agree. Nothing wrong with the code. If you're on py3.5 or above - and your internet connection is good - you could go with asyncio. Check this blogpost out: http://skipperkongen.dk/2016/09/09/easy-parallel-http-requests-with-python-and-asyncio/

Comment: @jlaur Thanks for the insight. I'll check the link out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to import `threading`. Just to use the same code as in the questions, here's the solution:

```
...
for link in generate_comic_link(found_comics, n_of_comics):
  print("Downloading: {}".format(link))
  url = grab_image_src_url(link)
  thread = threading.Thread(target=download_image, args=(url,))
  thread.start()
thread.join()
...
```

This actually cuts the download speed by almost `50%`, even for such a crude code as the one shown above.

The download time for a sample of `10` images is now approximately `21` seconds, compared to previous `> 40` sec.

Fully refactored code is [here](https://github.com/baduker/poorlywrittenscraper).